# Multiple SNMP managers on single PC

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

What I'm trying to do is use multiple instances of SNMP managers to get information out of devices (FM transmitters). In my use case one device could be disconnected which would have to wait for timeout or take time to respond. as a workaround for this I want to know if it's possible to start multiple instances and request simultaneously on all managers, one manager for one device. the manager I'm planning on using is net-snmp snmpget CLI application.

Comment: `snmpget` is a client, it contact "server". So no problem to run them simultaneously. Just keep the output of each of them in different file.

Comment: I looked at how browsers work and found an answer I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/1939817/20869943  so, If I got this correct, the client port is assigned dynamically so 2 instances of `snmpget` will get two different ports right?

Comment: That is correct, IMHO this answer answer too to your question.